# Getting a Range in Excel 2007, Is there still a row limit?

Tags: c#, excel, range

Please see the example below, this code works just fine if the rowLimit is less that 65536, I am using the Micorsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library, v1.6, does anybody know of a workaround or has this been fixed in a download?

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

long rowLimit = 65537;

object[,] items = new object[rowLimit, 5];

for( long rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowLimit; ++rowIndex )
{
    for( long columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 5; ++columnIndex )
    {
        items[rowIndex, columnIndex] = String.Format( "{0}-{1}", rowIndex, columnIndex );
    }
}

var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add( Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet );
var xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add();
xlWorkSheet.Name = "Test Sheet";

Excel.Range topLeft = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1];
Excel.Range bottomRight = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowLimit, 5]; // THIS LINE ALWAYS EXCEPTIONS IF rowLimit > 65536
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.Range[topLeft, bottomRight];
range.Value = items;
```

Comment: Odd, works for me same versions (c# 2k8) `Excel.Range bottomRight = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[999999, 5]; bottomRight.Value2 = "123"; xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(...)` behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Under Excel 2007 and Excel 2010, the sheets have 1048576 rows. I checked a slightly modified version of your code and it worked fine with the full number (long rowLimit = 1048576), though it took a while.

One of the changes from your code is that I removed the template in Workbooks.Add. Could your template be a problem - maybe it is an Excel 2003-style .xls file, and that limits the number of rows?

Comment: Thanks, still not sure why it doesn't work on my development machine, but it does work for everyone else.  I appreciate you taking a look at it.